# How to use autoyast to install an external package while installing Suse unattended?

Tags: suse

Recently I'm learning how to use autoyast to install SUSE unattendly via network with pxe.
My target is --

1. Unattended install Suse12.4 with pxe --  I have made it successfully with autoyast.xml and pxe
2. The install not only install Suse only, but also need to install some external packages -- eg.  rlwrap and puppet client...
   Follow the steps in https://documentation.suse.com/sles/12-SP4/html/SLES-all/configuration.html#CreateProfile-Software -- in Section 4.9.2
   So I made a test with rlwrap package only, here are my steps--
3. Since my repository was http://192.168.95.77/12.4, so I copied rlwrap-0.43-lp152.3.8.x86_64.rpm to http://192.168.95.77/12.4/suse/x86_64 and make sure it's available from http.
4. Then I modified my autoyast.xml add this at the file end--

   ```xml
   <add-on>
     <add_on_products config:type="list">
       <listentry>
         <media_url>http://192.168.95.77/12.4/suse/x86_64/rlwrap-0.43-lp152.3.8.x86_64.rpm</media_url>
         <product>rlwrap</product>
         <alias>rlwrap</alias>
         <product_dir></product_dir>
         <priority config:type="integer">99</priority>
         <ask_on_error config:type="boolean">false</ask_on_error>
         <confirm_license config:type="boolean">false</confirm_license>
         <name>eisen-repo-12.4</name>
       </listentry>
     </add_on_products>
   </add-on>
   ```

Then I tested with a new VM, -- then I found this VM was successfully installed Suse12.4 again, But that rlwrap package was not installed and there's no error message found in installation.

Comment: After 1 day's test. I found somehting new -- while I run "zypper install rlwrap" on this newly installed VM.  It reports --
rlwrap-0.43-lp152.3.8.x86_64.rpm:
    Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3dbdc284: NOKEY
    V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3dbdc284: NOKEY

rlwrap-0.43-lp152.3.8.x86_64 (http-192.168.95.77-897f574f): Signature verification failed [4-Signatures public key is not available]
Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i] (a): a
Maybe it's gpg keys error -- Anyone know how to set the GPG on the repository source side? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution --  the init.sh part in the autoyast.xml can do it.
I wrote it like this --

```
  <scripts>
    <init-scripts config:type="list">
      <script>
        <debug config:type="boolean">true</debug>
        <feedback config:type="boolean">false</feedback>
        <filename>init.sh</filename>
        <interpreter>shell</interpreter>
        <location><![CDATA[]]></location>
        <notification>customer initialization</notification>
        <source><![CDATA[
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/flag
rpm --import http://192.168.95.77/puppet7/repodata/repomd.xml.key 2>&1 >> /tmp/flag
zypper addrepo -f http://192.168.95.77/puppet7 eisen-repo-puppet7 2>&1 >> /tmp/flag
zypper install -y rlwrap 2>&1 >> /tmp/flag
zypper install -y puppet-agent 2>&1 >> /tmp/flag
        ]]></source>
      </script>
    </init-scripts>
  </scripts>
```

Then the 3rd party packages are installed successfully.